# Deriving a distance function with a fixed side of a triangle.

Tags: geometry

Dealing with a little bit of a headscratcher here.
What I'm trying to do (and struggling with) is deriving a function, r($\theta$). Given some box of length $l$, going from $\theta$=0 to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, I want to find the distance from the bottom-left corner (we'll just say that that's at the origin) to some point on the side.

At first, I just did r$^2$($\theta$)=$l^2$+$l^2$sin$^2$($\theta$), which seemed to make sense to me. The bottom side of the box being $l$, and the right side being at any given theta $l$sin($\theta$). But if we take the diagonal, we should get (using $l$ = 1 for simplicity here) r($\theta$)=$\sqrt2$. Plugging in $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ does not get us that value, but instead $\frac{3}{2}$, which makes me believe that it's a sin($2\theta$), but I don't even know where to begin with proving that. My intuition tells me it's $2\theta$ because we need a max value of sin = 1 at the corner.

I also understand the function to be symmetric around $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Any help or hints would be nice, thank you for your time!

Comment: $r^2 \ne l^2 + l^2 \sin^2 \theta $.  It is simply $ r= l \sec \theta $ where $0 \le \theta \le 45^\circ$, and $ r = l \csc \theta $ for $ 45^\circ \le \theta \le 90^\circ $

Comment: ...do I get to know where this comes from?

Comment: Most likely comes from the definitions of secant and cosecant.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In the image on the left, we have $\theta \lt 45^\circ$, and from the definition of $\cos(\theta)$ we have

$\cos(\theta) = \dfrac{a}{r} $

Therefore,

$ r = \dfrac{a}{\cos(\theta)} = a \sec(\theta) $

On the right we have $\theta \gt 45^\circ$, and from the definition of the $\sin(\theta)$,

$\sin(\theta) = \dfrac{ a }{r} $

Therefore,

$ r = \dfrac{a}{\sin(\theta)} = a \csc(\theta) $